# javascript--can't get textContent of [Object Text]?

Tags: javascript

I want the script to find where it says, "anyword" in the xml (within the tag of course), and stop on that.  the below accomplishes that fine.

```
 var xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc("nhl.xml");
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("tagname");
    for (var i=0;i<=x.length;i++){
        if (x[i].textContent = "anyword") {
            var variable = x[i].textContent;
        }
    }
```

However I want to take it one step further and be able to set 'variable' to the next node after it finds 'anyword'.  so i tried something like this and it came back with the very last element in the collection, instead of the next one.

```
var xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc("nhl.xml");
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("tagname");
    for (var i=0;i<=x.length;i++){
        if (x[i].textContent = "anyword") {
            var variable = x[i+1].textContent;
        }
    }
```

so i edited the last line again and made it

```
var variable = x[i].nextSibling.textContent;
```

this came back null.  ripping my hair out here.  if it helps to answer any, if i just put it `x[i].nextSibling` it comes back `[Object Text]`

any help?

Comment: [see this ans  to get the objext text][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646571/getting-the-value-of-text-from-a-text-object-in-javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By `x[i].textContent = "anyword"` do you mean `x[i].textContent == "anyword"`?

Comment: looks like i didn't have to filter my loop after all, thanks.

Comment: was looking for how to get the string out of the text. textContent helped.

Answer (score 4):

This is a common problem for people. The modern browsers (basically all them except IE) will add text nodes between elements. Those text nodes only contain the whitespace and aren't of a lot of use. Use this function to find the next node.

```
function nextSibling(node) {
  do {
    node = node.nextSibling;
  } while (node && node.nodeType != 1) ;
  return node
}
```

It gets explained pretty well here: [JavaScript XML Parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708400/javascript-xml-parsing/4708951#4708951)

Comment: thanks man.  which variable would node replace in my original script?  would it be variable?

Comment: pass x[i] into the function to get the next sibling.

Answer (score 0):

```
var xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc("nhl.xml");
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("tagname");
    for (var i=0;i<=x.length;i++){
        if (x[i].textContent = "anyword") {
            var variable = x[i+1].textContent;
        }
    }
```

I did't look in details but this seems odd to me :

```
for (var i=0;i<=x.length;i++)
```

Have you tried

```
for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++)
```

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, it makes more sense.. yet everything appears to be acting the same still